Pyinstaller и ошибка ModuleNotFound
Что я пишу в CMD Мои импорты
ошибка
что делать? я не знаю как добавить директорию для импортов. А так же дополнительных файлов(на всякий случай)
Вопрос: Как указать в pyinstaller при компиляции в exe файл сторонние библиотеки и дополнительные файла ( напишите два случая в ответе на мой основной вопрос а потом ответ) спасибо
